# Running a Jenkins job with a node parameter fails to mkdirs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

- I have added a Android Node in Jenkins.
- Now I am trying to run a Job with the Node as parameter
- It fails to mkdirs in workspace
- If i remove the Node as parameter, the Job runs fine

Plese find the screenshot for the Node I created. [image]

Log:
 - `Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on Android in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AndroidT
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AndroidT
at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1191)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1267)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by adding the "node as a parameter" to the job? The error message would suggest that the permissions are incorrect on the Android machine. Try logging in to the machine _as the jenkins user_ and see if you can run `mkdir -p /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AndroidT`.

Comment: Node as parameter means, I have a job which is parameterized that takes the Android node as one of its parameter.

Comment: Run node service executable as administrator and ensure it had read write permissions for target root folder

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution.

Jenkins is using '**jenkins**' user for auomation, but i had run the java command `java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://IP/computer/Android/slave-agent.jnlp -secret dadasdasdasd` tostart the node with another user.

I switched the user to jenkins, ran the command and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you intend to put your workspace in /var/lib/jenkins, since you probably don't have permissions to the path and it's not really for user files.

Instead, you should specify a workspace path that your executor should have access to. Look through the output of your successful, unspecified-node job and find the path to the workspace it was referring to, as in line 2:

Building remotely on Android in workspace **/var/lib/jenkins/** workspace/AndroidT

then use that path before /workspace as your node's remote root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the most basic reason that something cannot be written to disk:

- The user that running the Jenkins agent does not have write permission to your workspace `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/`
- The disk is full.  This is what happened to me.