# jenkins error in mkdir command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

```
started by user Monitorprov2
Building remotely on slave3 in workspace /home/ubuntu/workspace/test
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs: /home/ubuntu/workspace/test
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1171)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1210)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:566)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:491)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1737)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceC`enter code here`ontroller.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:419)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Am getting this error while executing Jenkins job so what would be the issue and how to resolve this

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly caused due to a permissions issue, where the user `jenkins` doesn't have permissions to create directories in the directory you're trying to do it in.

Here's a similar question: [Running a Jenkins job with a node parameter fails to mkdirs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854961/running-a-jenkins-job-with-a-node-parameter-fails-to-mkdirs)